# Is there a way I can assign every single textbox in a form to a single variable?

Tags: vb.net

```
txtRound.Text
txtDaysWorked.Text
txtPerGallon.Text
txtGasCost.Text
txtMaint.Text
txtParking.Text
txtInsure.Text
```

I have all these textboxes in a vb form and instead of checking every single one to make sure they are all positive numbers I want a more efficient way of checking them with one variable. Once that variable is declared I'll just go like this

```
If (dblVariable > 0) Then
```

A lot easier than a long list of checking

Comment: Pretty unclear why you assume a variable make the list shorter, you still have 7 of them.  Write a method that takes a TextBox argument.  Create a List(Of TextBox) and add the text boxes.  Use For Each.

Answer (score 5):

Your form has a `Controls` properties which is a list of all controls on that form.

You can loop through each control and check it is a `TextBox`, and if so set it's Text property.

If LINQ is available you could simplify this to

```
For Each control In myForm.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
    control.Text = "My Value"
Next
```

Re-read the question, the title is a bit misleading, but I get what you're asking now.

Again, assuming LINQ is available you should use the `.All` extension.

```
If Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().All(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(x.Text) > 0) Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to set the value, but rather check it. Other than that, great answer.

Comment: @CyberneticianDave That depends on whether to focus on the title (`assign`) or the code snippet which tests (sort of) the contents

Comment: Also mention accessing nested controls. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: The question assumes the same algorithm proposed in the question, that of assigning every variable to one variable, somehow, which seems overly complicated in practice. However, the use of Linq's `.All` method is a brilliant solution to the actual problem!

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko with a few adjustments (If Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().All(Function(x) Convert.ToDouble(x.Text) > 0) Then) it worked

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a vague answer, because I'm working from memory, but here's my best attempt.

In short, I don't think so. If you want to check one variable you're going to have to generate that variable yourself. You could do this client-side.

Alternatively, if all of these controls are within a single form or something, you might be able to cycle through each control in a loop to check each one.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a function which takes the list of TextBoxes:

```
Private Function CheckValues(txt As TextBox()) As Boolean
  For Each member In txt 
     If not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(member.Text) Then
         Dim number As Integer = CInt(member.Text)
         If number < 0 Then
            Return False 

   Next
   Return true 'all positives
End Function
```

And then call it like this:

```
 If CheckValues(new TextBox(){txtRound, txtDaysWorked}) Then
      'case true
  Else
      'case false
  End If
```